# Page controller not at change when page scroll

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

The Horizontal Scroll will work fine, but UIpagecontroller will not work means  it will not change, As I scroll the page. I can't able to identify the error. Please see below code

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController ()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pgcnt;



    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSArray *arry=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"e",@"f", nil];
        for (int i=0; i<arry.count; i++) {
            CGRect frame;
            [self.scroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
            _scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;

            _scroll.bounces = YES;
            [_scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
            [_scroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

            frame.origin.x=_scroll.frame.size.width*i;


            frame.size=_scroll.frame.size;

            UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arry objectAtIndex:i]]];


            [_scroll addSubview:view];

            [self.pgcnt setCurrentPage:i];
           // self.pgcnt.numberOfPages=arry.count;


        }

     _scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_scroll.frame.size.width*arry.count,_scroll.frame.size.height);


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Any suggestion or help will appreciated

Comment: How are you managing your PageControl ?
It seems that you're simply not using it. All you're doing is putting views in a scrollview.
You don't need to manage a ScrollView AND a PageControl.
But if you want, you can use UIScrollViewDelegate to update your PageControl current page.

Comment: APgecontroll count is working fine. but it will not move @KIDdAe

Comment: [self.pgcnt setCurrentPage:i];
        self.pgcnt.numberOfPages=arry.count; // this will work fine. but setcurrentpage not woks @KIDdAe

Comment: Are you updating the currentPage when the scrollview move to next Index ? Could you show this code ? And where it's called ?

Comment: yes , i gave it na [self.pgcnt setcurrentpage:i] , here i contain index right. @KIDdAe

Comment: Please tell me what i did wrong ... simply dont make negative mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution , no one helped me, but its ok, i will help other people .i Didn't added delegate method thats why the Pagecontrol dot will not worked. But now working fine.

## pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scroll.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pgcnt.currentPage = page;
}
```

thanks for
http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html